# String not found when using strpos()

Tags: php

Why it is not returning good? Really strange.

```
<?php
$r = "<h3>Welcome</h3>";
if (strpos($r, "​Welcome") !== FALSE) {
    echo "Good";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you see the little `​` box? That is `E2 80 8B` in UTF-8, the zero-width space.
And that's not present in your source text.

---

[image]

Comment: Good catch! I didn't see  ` ` box from netbeans editor... hmmm. How did you work that out?

Comment: He may not see it (I didn't) because Chrome actually rendered it "correctly" - i.e. it was invisible. I only caught it when I tried to copy/paste the code into a ISO-8859-1 editor.

Comment: @DaveRandom It not visible in Chrome I am using and even text editor netbeans.

Comment: It depends on browser and font configuration. I'm using Opera, which shows the box as depicted. It's supposed to be an invisible character of course. Such things are virtually impossible to guess and see unless you switch your editor into hex mode.

Comment: @user791022 If you don't need any literal fancy characters, switch the character set in netbeans to a unibyte character set (such as ISO-8859-1)

Answer (score 1):

Strange, it works for me (see [codepad](http://codepad.org/jst9QvKl)):

```
<?php
$r = "<h3>Welcome</h3>";
if (strpos($r, "Welcome") !== FALSE) {
    echo "Good";
}
```

> Good

However, I rewrote the string because in your code it contains a hidden character. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work - the logic is fine.

However, there is a funny character in there somewhere - I presume you have copy/pasted this code from somewhere?

When I copy the code off this page into my editor, it complains that there is a character that cannot be represented in my character set, and `strpos($r, "​Welcome")` becomes `strpos($r, "?Welcome")`.

This does not happen for the input string so they won't match.